# Unable to unpack (loop iterate) for all keys with related pairs (values)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I know that when creating dict, the key(s) must be unique, but each key can have multiple values,
take for example:

This is the dict:

```
d = {1:a, 2:[a,b,c], 3:[e,f,g]}
```

What I want to do is to use for loop in python to extract the keys and associated values and turn all into list results, so that I can then make two parallel lists:

Expect result for key:

`listA: [1,2,2,2,3,3,3]`

Expect result for values:

`listB: [a,a,b,c,e,f,g]`

For list B, I can do the code to finish it:

```
listkey = [] #assign a list container
listvalue = [] #assign a list container

for k,v in d.items():
    listkey.append(k)
    listvalue.append(v)

listB = [ item for elem in listvalue for item in elem]

listB result success: [a,a,b,c,e,f,g]
```

However, for listA,

```
listA = [ item for elem1 in listvalue for item in elem1]
it just results [1,2,3],but not [1,2,2,2,3,3,3]
```

I am wondering what's wrong with my code. Can I achieve this by using for loop?

Comment: Does that mean there is no way to unpack the result like this from dict? The dict is easy to categorize the structuring, but it seems quite hard to extract all out for usage, as list for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample input is inconsistent (one of the dictionary value is not a list).  If it were consistent you could use list comprehensions with nested for loops to get the two lists:

```
d = {1:['a'], 2:['a','b','c'], 3:['e','f','g']}

listA = [ k for k,v in d.items() for _ in range(len(v)) ]
listB = [ c for v in d.values() for c in v ]

print(listA)  # [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
print(listB)  # ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

The list comprehensions are equivalent to nested for loops:

```
# [ k for k,v in d.items() for _ in range(len(v)) ]

listA = []
for k,v in d.items():
    for _ in range(len(v)):
        listA.append(k)

# [ c for v in d.values() for c in v ]
listB = []
for v in d.values():
    for c in v:
        listB.append(v)
```

Comment: Because I am new to python, it seems the list comprehension right now is quite hard for me to understand the structure.  Is that possible to change struture like:But I know it works.

Comment: Thank you. I tested and works perfectly. The trick for the key is to use  range(len(v),

Comment: I never use range(len) before. I am studying how it use value apply for key.

Comment: Actually  `for _ in range(len(v))` is a bit overkill.  I only used it to make it clear that the k would be repeated for the same numer of times as the number of items in the value's list. `for _ in v` would have accomplished the same thing.

Comment: Yes, I tested. This is for me to understand the order structure. I can leave it by using the simple for _in v. Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

It is often simpler to handle the values of the same type in a dict. So I have converted the first value into a list in this answer.

You can use nested comprehension and a `zip`:

```py
d = {1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3: ['e', 'f', 'g']}

key_value = ((k, v) for k, l in d.items() for v in l)
a, b = zip(*key_value)
print(a) # (1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3)
print(b) # ('a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g')
```

If you do want `a` and `b` as lists, you can use instead:

```py
a, b = map(list, zip(*key_value))
# [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
# ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

EDIT: using plain nested for loop:

```py
d = {1: ['a'], 2: ['a', 'b', 'c'], 3: ['e', 'f', 'g']}

a, b = [], []
for key, lst in d.items():
    for val in lst:
        a.append(key)
        b.append(val)

print(a) # [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
print(b) # ['a', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'e', 'f', 'g']
```

Comment: Thank you J1-lee. I found the trick is the zip(*key_value), let me study how it works.

Comment: Because I am new to python, it seems the list comprehension right now is quite hard for me to understand the structure. Is that possible to change the structure? Especially when I use key_value.append not able to use for turning all result to turple (if I understand right). Also, I saw that the last code is a, b = zip(*key_value), which I am confused to understand. Thank you for help as well.

Comment: @RyanYeung Please check the updated answer. I hope it is better now.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution :

In the time that you want add the value use `list.extend` instead of append:

```
a = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
b = [ 4, 5, 6 ]

a.extend(b)
```

The result it that a will put b elemnts in itself. :)

Comment: The problem is that the keys are unique. Combining keys and values to lists is not what I want. Or I misunderstand your answer. Thank you.